# IFTTT to WordPress issue

Tags: wordpress, youtube, ifttt

I'm using IFTTT to post new YouTube videos automatically to WordPress. Every time I upload new video, a new WP post should be generated with this HTML code:

```
[vc_row row_height_percent="0" overlay_color="color-396201" 
overlay_alpha="100" gutter_size="3" column_width_percent="100" 
shift_y="0" z_index="0"][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text]

<div class="responsive-video">

https://youtu.be/"videoID"

</div>
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"]   
[uncode_block id="67020"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

When IFTTT posts this on WordPress, it works! BUT: IFTTT does not post the correct code -  instead it posts this:

```
[vc_row row_height_percent="0" overlay_color="color-396201" 
overlay_alpha="100" gutter_size="3" column_width_percent="100" 
shift_y="0" z_index="0"][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text]
<div class="responsive-video">https://youtu.be/"videoID"</div>
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"]   
[uncode_block id="67020"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

So IFTTT posts the code without those "spaces" before/after the video URL. And because of that WordPress doesn't automatically embed the video. (It doesn't recognize the URL as a video without those spaces... So on the post the video URL is displayed just as a normal text.
Any idea how to tell IFTTT to keep those "spaces" in the code, so WordPress embeds the video?

Answer (score 0):

if you can put `<br>` for in between spaces

```
[vc_row row_height_percent="0" overlay_color="color-396201" 
overlay_alpha="100" gutter_size="3" column_width_percent="100" 
shift_y="0" z_index="0"][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text]

<div class="responsive-video">

https://youtu.be/"videoID"

</div>
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"]   
[uncode_block id="67020"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```